# "attempt to write a readonly database" with BrowserTestBase Functional tests

Tags: testing, 9

I have a functional test that is currently empty. I run it with the following command;

```
php core/scripts/run-tests.sh --sqlite /db/drupal.sqlite --php /usr/local/bin/php --verbose --directory modules/custom/
```

I have tried with and without the `--sqlite` command, as well as trying a non-existant file like `tmpfs/drupal.sqlite`, but I always get the same error:

> 1. Drupal\Tests\answers\Functional\AnswersTest::testAddContentPage
>    Exception: Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper:
>    SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 8 attempt to write a readonly
>    database:

From that error I have gathered that the issue is that the user doesn't have write-access to the database, but without knowing *where* the database file is I'm not sure how to check this. I tried settings the permissions on */db/drupal.sqlite* to 777 but this didn't help either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand *why* this fixes the problem, but in my case the issue was caused by my executing the `core/scripts/run-tests.sh` script as `root`. By running it as `www-data` instead the issue went away.

I can only assume that the sqlite DB gets created by `root` and then the script switches itself over to `www-data` and can't access the DB anymore.